# Data Spyre - Python Framework for Web Applications - Import Error

Tags: python, web-applications, frameworks

I am learning to use Data Spyre. The installation was successful. But I was unable to import the packages.

```
from spyre import server
```

---

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
    ----> 1 from spyre import server

```
C:\Users\prashanth\Documents\spyre.py in <module>()

----> 1 from spyre import server
  2 
  3 class SimpleApp(server.App):
  4     title = "Simple App"
  5     inputs = [{ "type":"text",
```

ImportError: cannot import name server

Any suggestions would be of much help. Is there any other alternative framework I can use to build simple python web applications (A Data Product that resembles the examples given in Data Spyre Github page)

Comment: The name `spyre.py` clashes with the module `spyre`. You just have to rename it.

Comment: Thank you. The name change has worked. The cmd is showing the Engine serving on some http IP address. But it does not open any Browser tab or HTML page to show the app.

Comment: Please open a new question for the new problem.